# use lets encrypt local with Spring Boot

Tags: lets-encrypt

I wanted to do this tutorial

[lets encrypt local](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-spring-boot-webapp-apache-letsencrypt-ssl)

but I do not know what to do here:

> Add LetsEncrypt
>   LetsEncrypt has policies against generating certificates for certain domains. amazonaws.com is one of them (because they are normally transient). You need to add a CNAME to a personal domain that points to the instance you created. Here I’m using kewp.net.za.

is there any tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a CNAME is done either in a GUI particular to your DNS service or in files on your own DNS servers.

Each service should have its own administration guide/help section. For example:
[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/how-to/manage-records/#cname-records) (Whichever registrar you register your domain with is also likely to provide a free dns service with a similar web interface.)

Irregardless of where you are adding it, the DNS record's essential fields are always the same: (source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record))

```
 NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
 --------------------------------------------------
 bar.example.com.        CNAME  foo.example.com.
```

Here:

- bar.example.com. could be springtutorial.mydomain.com. or just written as springtutorial without a '.' to indicate it is a complete name.
- foo.example.com. would be randomid.amazonaws.com.

So:

```
 NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
 --------------------------------------------------
 myalias                 CNAME  xyznodenumber.amazonaws.com.
```